# Setting up Optimizely with Angular.js but scope is undefined

Tags: angularjs, ab-testing, optimizely

We're running Optimizely on our Angular.js single page app. According to the documentation the best way to trigger the experiment is using [conditional activation with a callback](http://developers.optimizely.com/javascript/code-samples/index.html#conditional-activation-angular-page-change).

However, the code doesn't seem to run the experiment successfully as `window.angular.element('body').scope()` would return `undefined`

The way I understand it is that the main Optimizely script in HTML would call the activation function immediately on load and register a callback. At this point, the page itself might not be fully loaded and all the Angular variables (such as `scope`) not initialized, hence the `undefined` error which causes nothing to be registered on `$locationChangeSuccess`.

Anyone have experience dealing with this issue? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a link to reproduce the issue with the running experiment? And of course the code you're using in this experiment's (function type) conditional activation, [here](https://help.optimizely.com/hc/en-us/articles/200040225#conditional)? Also just thinking, does the issue occur only on hard page refresh (i.e. it works when you load the home page, and then move to product page, which should trigger a location change event)?